# Trouble updating Jquery mobile ui slider programmatically after sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Ive created a jQuery mobile site that works like it should on all desktop browsers, tested in IE, chrome and firefox and works like a charm. However when I open the same site on for example an iphone or ipad with either safari or firefox it doesn't do what is supposed to be doing..

Some extra background info: the mobile site runs on a piece of hardware that sends out data. This data needs to be read and should be able to be altered with the mobile UI Slider. Jquery mobile version used:

On $(document).ready() I programmatically set each slider to match the corresponding data output channel, so slider 1 should match the first channel of the data output value. Since its possible that the data changes from time to time i need to make sure to keep checking the output data which i do with the window.setTimeout() function every 100ms. I then also set the value of the sliders and refresh them.

Now this all works, the sliders get updated and whenever data from the output of the hardware changes the sliders change as well. But the sliders are there for the user to alter this data and this is where I'm getting stuck on. Whenever a slider has been changed the sliders stop updating their values, the hardware responds to the slider change only the jquery mobile site stops updating. While I adjusted the slider I check the webpage on a desktop and here the values keep updating and also the slider change that has been done on the mobile is seen.

To me it looks like it keeps hanging on an event that's being created but I couldn't find this out..

Ive created a simplified example of my code in jfiddle and was hoping someone can help me out or point me in the right direction, much appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Retrieve data from output
  get_output(OUTPUT1, function update(t) {

      $("#slider1").val(t.values[0]).slider("refresh"); //Get data output for first channel
      console.log("Data output channel 1: " + t.values[0]);
      window.setTimeout(function() {
          get_output(OUTPUT1
          }, update);
      }, 100); // refresh every 100ms 
  });


$("#slider1").change(function() {
  SliderMoved(this.value, 0);
  $.throttle(300, true, SliderValueChanged(0));
});

});


//Store copy of slider value.
function SliderMoved(value, channel) {
  send_data(OUTPUT1, channel, value);
  newValue = value;
}


function SliderValueChanged(channel) {
  //check if same data doesnt get output the same
  if (LastValue[channel] != newValue[channel]) {
    LastValue[channel] = newValue[channel];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="slider1">Slider:</label>
  <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="0" min="0" max="255" data-highlight="true" />
</div>


<button type="button" id="setting1" onclick="fire(1)">Setting1</button>
<button type="button" id="setting2" onclick="fire(2)">Setting2</button>
```

Comment: Instead of $(document).ready(function() {..., try the jQM pagecreate event: $(document).on("pagecreate","#yourpageid", function(){ ...